# How can I make a puzzle table with div element like this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how can I make a puzzle table with div element in javascript?
It is essential for me to use div.

```
function puzzle() {
    var puzzleTable = document.createElement("div");
    puzzleTable.style.width = "400px";
    puzzleTable.style.height = "400px";
    puzzleTable.style.marginTop = "200px";
    puzzleTable.style.marginLeft = "450px";
    puzzleTable.style.border="1px solid black";
    document.body.appendChild(puzzleTable);
    var cell=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var cells = document.createElement("div");
            cells.style.width = "25px";
            cells.style.height = "25px";
            cells.style.marginTop = "2px";
            cells.style.border = "1px solid black";
            document.body.appendChild(cells);
            cell[i,j]=new cell[i,j,cell.value()];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "puzzle table"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many live examples and demos some links are given below.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/08/jqpuzzle-customizable-sliding-puzzles-with-jquery/

http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/09/how-to-create-a-puzzle-game-using-jquery/

http://dhirajkumarsingh.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/creating-puzzle-game-with-jquery/

Hope this helps you!